# How to use S3 VPC endpoint in aws sdk(javascript) for upload and download?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have the S3 VPC endpoint, and how it can be used for upload and download using AWS-SDK javascript?

Comment: Is it a Gateway or an Interface Endpoint? Where is your code running (Lambda, EC2, ...?)

Comment: Related docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#accessing-s3-interface-endpoints).

Answer (score 1):

When you create such an endpoint, you should make sure the endpoint is listed in the routing table.
Having routing in place will allow all requests run within your VPC to be directed through the endpoint.
This will also make the endpoint totally transparent to the code running in your VPC, so there won't be any need for using endpoint-url params in any S3 call.

To verify connection to S3 through the endpoint, please run any compute resource in an isolated subnet (no Internet Gateway, No NAT Gateway, no egress-only gateway), with only the S3 endpoint attached to the related routing table.